# How can I return the right value?

Tags: java, arrays

I need to return `-1` if one of this two conditions: `biggerThanK(array[i], k)`, or `prim(array[i])` return `false`. I tried to put an `else { smallest = -1; }` but if I input values that respect both conditions it still displays `-1`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int smallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int k = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[n];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (biggerThanK(array[i], k) && prim(array[i])) {
                if (array[i] < smallest) {
                    smallest = array[i];
                }
            }   
        }
        System.out.println(smallest);
    }

    public static boolean biggerThanK(int number, int k) {
        if (number >= k) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean prim(int number) {
        for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }  return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us the inputs you are using that are failing? and then what you would expect to be outputted.

Comment: Well inputs are random. This code must pass some tests on a platform for my University. I need to return from an array the smallest prime number that is bigger than "k". If it doesn't exist I need to return -1 to pass the test. So I'm stuck to this point because if I put else { smallest = -1} it stay -1 all the time. For an example : k = 5 and numbers from the array are : 3, 6, 7, 13. It need to return 7, but if I put else {smallest = -1;} the program will display -1 what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

You should put this in a function.

If only one of the conditions needs to be false, I would use an architecture like this :

```
if(condition 1)
    if(condition 2)
        //update smallest
    else
        return -1
else 
    return -1
```